# Why do Pop3Client download multiple same email from POP3 Server at current times?

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook

I could face to the problem that Pop3Clients download multiple same mail from Pop3Server at certain times .I could not find out the reason of it.Please anyone suggest me some information then i will solve that problem.